# how to make a php page to send data to other page?

Tags: php, button, onclick

How can I make a php page so that when I click on the button,another page is created with the text like as "Hello World"

And It all must be happened on the website.

It would be great of you if you can help!

Thank YOu

Comment: Typically a php process does _not_ have local permissions to create files, since that would be a _huge_ security problem. If it has, then you just use phps file commands to create a file and put text into it. I suggest you take a look at the php documentation for this. It is of high quality and contains good examples: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: can it make changes in the already created php file??

Comment: Same thing: that means that the process has to have write access to local files. Which again is a huge security problem, since it allows all attackers to do the same. In theory you can implement a save page like that, but that is risky, since you can never know if there are holes that can be exploited (the issue of "unknown unknowns"...). Which is why a meaningful security strategy will always deny that permission. But again: it is possible, technically spoken, so have a try. Maybe your webspace provider has such a "liberal" security concept...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have way to little information to really help you.

But it is possible to send a  variable to another page by pressing a button.
You need to create 2 files: home.php and message.php.

home.php, the page from where we sent our message. Change value to whatever message you are trying to send

```
<form action="test4.php" methode="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="Hello World">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

message.php, the page where we receive our message

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    echo $_POST['text'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks PHPeter for the help :)